# In mixed-system Linux/Win network render, is there a way to specify cache directory?

Tags: network

I'm using the network render addon (using blender 2.78 on all machines) to render an animation on a network of computers (Master is Windows; slaves are Ubuntu). The animation uses several physics simulations, and each slave starts rendering each simulation as if it started in the batch of 5 frames it receives.

The .blend file and the cache are stored on a Windows directory which is shared with the slaves, but every time I attempt to render I get the message "still missing dependency file".

I'm using relative paths, but it seems like the ubuntu slaves don't know where the cache is, since paths in Windows/Ubuntu work differently.

Does Blender have a place where a cache directory can be manually specified for a slave node, or has anyone encountered a similar issue that they've been able to resolve. Thanks!